# jQuery post return variable

Tags: jquery, post

I need to set the width of a table based on a Javascript variable coming from a jQuery post.

```
$.post("get.php", {this: 'that'}, function(data){ 
var width = data // eg '300'

? set table width to 'width'
```

I'm new when it comes to jQuery, I know how to set the return into a div tag, but I'm guessing that won't help me in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert to numeric value using `parseInt` then just set the `width` property of the jQuery object:

```
var width = parseInt(data, 10);
$("#myTable").width(width);
```

"myTable" should be changed to the ID of the actual `<table>` element.

Answer (score 0):

as Shadow Wizard said, here is the jquery docs page
http://api.jquery.com/width/